# HTML Text Input allow only two-digit Numeric input

Tags: jquery, input, numbers

I am new to JQuery world and I am trying to limit the number of digits in some of the text field inputs in the webpage that I am working on it right now.
I would like to allow the user:

1. to enter a number of two digits only
2. the number should not exceed the value of 12, so he can enter numbers from 0 to 12 such as; 8, 11, 6.5

**How can I do that?**

Here's what I have done so far.
**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="text" class="txt input-sm" />
<input type="text" class="txt input-sm" />
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
<script>
            $(function(){
                $(".txt").on("keypress", function(){
                    if($(".txt").val().length > 2)
                    {
                        this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: so you want to have numbers from 0 to 12, but what about numbers in between? Do you want to enforce some limit to decimal places as well?

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery to remove the unwanted key characters then check to see if the value is greater than 12. The first event is `keydown` to see if the character pressed is allowed. I added another event for `keyup` because the value wasn't being registered until after "keyup"

```
$(".txt.input-sm").keydown(function (event) {

    //prevent using shift with numbers
    if (event.shiftKey == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if (!((event.keyCode == 190) || (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 46)) {
        //not a number key or period so prevent
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$(".txt.input-sm").keyup(function (event) {

    var number = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if(number > 12){
       $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/94ayn8b6/4/)

**UPDATE**

This is tricky because of the decimal but you can do something like use a counter to track clicks.

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/94ayn8b6/4/)

Comment: thank you very much for your help. However, I need your help in the following: when the user tries to enter the third digit, I want the system to prevent him from entering that digit (with keeping the other two digits he entered) and to show him a meaningful message. **How can I do that in your code?**

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="12">
```

Comment: You need to add step attribute to handle float numbers as `6.5`

Answer (score 0):

So I actually completed a solution to this question two days ago, but I had to leave before I could post an answer.  If you still need help, here's something to look at, though it probably has more features than you need--I was having fun :)

```
$(".txt").on("keyup", function(event) {

    // don't handle backspace, delete, pgup/pgdn, home/end, or arrow keys:
    if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode >= 33 && event.keyCode <= 40) return false;

    var currentEl = $(this);
    var value = $(currentEl).val();

    // remove letters...
    value = value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, "");

    var hasDecPlace = value.match(/\./);

    // separate integer from decimal places:
    var pieces = value.split('.');
    var integer = pieces[0].replace('-', '');
    var decPlaces = ""
    if (pieces.length > 1)
    {
        pieces.shift();
        decPlaces = pieces.join('').replace('-', '');
    }

    // handle numbers greater than 12.00... :
    if (parseInt(integer) > 12 || parseInt(integer) === 12 && parseInt(decPlaces) > 0)
    {
        integer = "12";
        decPlaces = getZeroedDecPlaces(decPlaces);
        alert("number must be between 0.00 and 12.00");
    } // ...and less than 0:
    else if (parseInt(integer) < 0)
    {
        integer = "0";
        decPlaces = getZeroedDecPlaces(decPlaces);
        alert("number must be between 0.00 and 12.00");
    }

    // handle more than two decimal places:
    if (decPlaces.length > 2)
    {
        decPlaces = decPlaces.substr(0, 2);
        alert("number cannot have more than two decimal places");
    }

    var newVal = hasDecPlace ? integer + '.' + decPlaces : integer;

    $(currentEl).val(newVal);
});

function getZeroedDecPlaces(decPlaces) {
    if (decPlaces === '') return '';
    else if (decPlaces.length === 1) return '0';
    else if (decPlaces.length >= 2) return '00';
}
```

--First of all, handle the `keyup` event--values aren't added to inputs until after `keypress` or `keydown`

--Don't handle certain keys (`return false`).  You can add more to this list.

--Next, an unorthodox approach, handle the number as a string: If you really don't want to use a `<input type="number" />` tag, resort to regex to take letters and other junk out of the "number".

--Now, first, determine if there is a decimal point so you can reconstruct the "number" (string) later.  Next, separate the integer from the decimal places.

--Now handle numbers greater than 12.00 or less than 0.00 by parsing the integer (and the decimal places, if the `number === 12`).  I used a function (`getZeroedDecimalPlaces`) to avoid adding extra zeroes to, or removing numbers from, the user's string.

--Next limit the number of decimal places.  I don't know if you wanted this.  I limited it to two decimal places, but it can be set to whatever.

--Finally, reconstruct the string and stick it in the input

[**Here is the JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/997g3fug/1/)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here are ideal. Here is my solution:

```js
$( function() {
  $(document).on('input', '.spinner', function() {
    
    var allowedDigits = 2;
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    var max = parseInt($(this).attr("max"));
    
    // appears there is a bug in the latest version of Chrome. When there are multiple decimals,
    // the value of a number type field can no longer be accessed. For now, all we can do is clear it
    // when that happens
    if($(this).val() == ""){
      $(this).val("");
    }
    
    if ($(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) {
      allowedDigits = 3;
    }
    
    if(length > allowedDigits){
      $(this).val($(this).val().substring(1));
  }
    
    if($(this).val() > max && max > 0){
      $(this).val($(this).val().substring(1));
    }
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="spinner" type="number" min="0" value="00" max="12">
```

This will allow you to type in any number that is 2 digits and below 12, without interruption. It will drop off the leftmost number when there is too many digits.